How can i put copy in the ListTile?
I want if Someone long press on ListTile, than copy the Text..
Here is snippet of my code,
Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.call,
                    color: Colors.teal,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    '+11 11111 11111',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily: 'EncodeSansExpanded',
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ),

I want to do like, anyone long-press on it than copy the number in above code..

Try below answer when you longPressed on ListTile it will copy the your data. Read more about Clipboard
Import below package:
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

UI:
Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
        child: ListTile(
          onLongPress: () async {
            await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: '+11 11111 11111'))
                .then(
              (_) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Data Copied'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.call,
            color: Colors.teal,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            '+11 11111 11111',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'EncodeSansExpanded',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),


you could do something like this:
first declare the text you are trying to copy as a variable:
String text = '+11 11111 11111';

then wrap you code in a GestureDetector Widget a use the onLongPress method and us import flutter services to use Clipboard.setdata like this
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


GestureDetector(
              onLongPress: () async {
                await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: text));  //<- copy to clipboard functionality 
              },
              child: Card(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.call,
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      text, //<- your text here
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontFamily: 'EncodeSansExpanded',
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),


Wrap you card with "GestureDetector" then pass the text to the Clipboard.setData.
Here is the an example.
Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: phoneNumber));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text('Phone number copied to clipboard!'),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.call,
            color: Colors.teal,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            phoneNumber,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'EncodeSansExpanded',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


You can embed Card in SelectionArea
Like this:
    SelectionArea(
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0, vertical: 10.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.call,
            color: Colors.teal,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
          title: Text(
            '+11 11111 11111',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'EncodeSansExpanded',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )

